# How to Solve a Stationary Dual Function for Calculus of Variation? Tricky

Tags: calculus, integration, calculus-of-variations, integration-by-parts

Determine the stationary function u(x) for the dual functional
$$I[u]=-u(\pi)u'(\pi)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}[(u')^2-u^2+2u]dx$$

I am having a difficult time solving this problem. I am not sure how to go about the integration by parts and the rest. The answer provided is $u(x)=cosx+1$. 
If you could explain in detail how to solve this problem I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: By the way I am new to this site! So any advice you guys have would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Why do you call the functional "dual"? 2. Have you tried applying [Euler-Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) to the problem?

Comment: This is exactly how the professor worded the question. I am actually not sure why he said it is dual functional? And no I haven't I wasn't even able to get the integration by parts.

Comment: Possibly some hints?

Comment: Technically, in a well-posed variational problem, one needs to impose pertinent boundary conditions to consistently derive Euler-Lagrange equation. What are the boundary conditions here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve the problem

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{u}} \right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial u} = 0 \tag{1}
$$

where

$$
L(u, \dot{u}) = \frac{1}{2}\dot{u}^2 - \frac{1}{2}u^2 + u
$$

Eq. (1) then becomes

$$
\ddot{u} - (-u + 1) = 0 ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ \frac{d^2 u}{dt^2} + u = 1
$$

whose solutions are

$$
u(t) = 1 + a\cos t  + b\sin t
$$

Some additional information will be required to solve the problem, such as the value of $u$ at the borders of the domain $u(0)$ and $u(\pi)$